# Access Denied - S3 resource using Pre Signed URL - PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, sdk

I am generating a Pre Signed URL to allow users to download files from an S3 Bucket. I am generating the URL's via the PHP SDK using the following code:

```
public static function get_content_link( $bucket, $key ) {

    //check response code from AWS
    require_once 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => 'MY-KEY',
            'secret' => 'MY-SECRET',
        ],
    ]);

    $cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key
    ]);

    $request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+500 minutes');

    // Get the actual presigned-url
    $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

    return $presignedUrl;
}
```

The URLs are being returned as expected, for example:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/MY-BUCKET-NAME/product/3166_1480009917388.mov?x-amz-content-sha256=unsigned-payload&x-amz-algorithm=aws4-hmac-sha256&x-amz-credential=akiaiqrmkn276hcpjkaq%2f20161127%2feu-west-1%2fs3%2faws4_request&x-amz-date=20161127t145603z&x-amz-signedheaders=host&x-amz-expires=30000&x-amz-signature=98eaef504f053ca56908ac49c6539c4a8b8e250d7d3a4a12460f4a806ec41c19
```

When I try to open any of the returned links in the browser I am getting an access denied error from S3:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>A37839BB23186F72</RequestId>
  <HostId>
yvKTN+CN1TTNk2tqoxxm3MPOGTUSMaRYtbbEFeCzGP7ou5IYf37Z9uBESwUQWDIUR1GUuPbZyuM=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

The files that I want to provide access to are in a bucket which contains folders allowing public access, by the folder I am trying to access is private (called /product/). Our bucket policy looks like this:

```
{
        "Version": "2008-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AllowPublicReadProxies",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "*"
                },
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/proxies*"
            },
            {
                "Sid": "AllowPublicReadThumbs",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "*"
                },
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/thumbs*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

It is my understanding that the purpose of creating a Pre Signed URL is to allow unauthenticated users temporary access to protected files without having to modify the bucket or folder permissions.

Has anyone got any ideas as to what I have missed or done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you grant the IAM user associated with this AWS Access Key Id the necessary permission to perform `s3:GetObject`?

Comment: Can you try generating the pre-signed URL using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) just to confirm that permissions work? The command to use is [`aws s3 presign`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html). Then, compare the URLs to ensure that all elements match (but the values will differ). Your 'expires' time seems incorrect in the URL you provided. The pre-signed URL does not rely on bucket policies -- it is an alternate way of providing access.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I am using a root access key rather than a specific IAM User.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks, I'll try that out.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have created an IAM User and granted them the AmazonS3FullAccess permission policy. Are there additional permissions that they would need? I'm still seeing the same access denied error.

Comment: Wait a minute, @JohnRotenstein, "the pre-signed URL does not rely on bucket policies -- it is an alternate way of providing access."  To be clear, they don't *require* bucket policies, but they are still *subject to* bucket policies (such as a policy denying access, or granting access to the user owning the key).

Comment: Wait a minute... how is the entire query string getting coerced to lower case?  That's definitely invalid.  I can replicate this by converting a valid, working signed URL to all-lowercase.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That was the problem.. I have been forcing the entire URL to be lowercase rather than just the filename! Thanks so much for spotting that. The 'Access denied' error totally threw me off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to @Michael-sqlbot for figuring this out for me.

It turns out I was forcing the entire URL to be lowercase when outputting the pre signed URL to the page, so AWS was returning an Access Denied error due to the fact that the resource technically didn't exist.

Comment: Well, technically, the access denied error was caused by S3 overlooking the lowercase `x-amz-*` query string parameters, and concluding that you were not actually offering any credentials that it should be trying to validate.  You can essentially prove this by changing *just one* of them to all lowercase.  S3 will suddenly complain with a new error message that tells you it's missing.  Change them all to lower and that message goes away because S3 assumes it's an anonymous request, no credentials provided.

Comment: Yeah, I think the common problem here is the url format or encoding. I encountered a similar problem, but instead of things being lowercase, the url formatting was being lost because I was using curl, but wasn't putting quotes around the url string

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error, also make sure you are not doing a GET request to the presigned url, instead of a POST request.